# Discord.js client immediately crashing as soon as a member joins

Tags: discord.js

I have a Discord bot that is supposed to check the user info of a server member as soon as they join. Yet, what happens as soon as a member joins is that the client immediately crashes.
Thank you in advance for reading this. If I am doing anything else wrong in this code, let me know!
This is the code where the event is:

**Error:**

```js
/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:349
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:349:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async GuildMemberManager.kick (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildMemberManager.js:344:5) {   method: 'delete',   path: '/guilds/900147696902479942/members/817852730197671996',   code: 50013,   httpStatus: 403,   requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] } }
```

**Code:**

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
   if (Date.now() - member.user.createdAt < 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 10) {
       const role = interaction.options.getRole('test');
  member.roles.add(role)
}
    else
        member.kick()
});
```

Comment: bot needs manage role perm, and the role needs to be lower than the bot's highest role

Comment: The bot does indeed have a manage role perm; and the role is indeed lower than the bot's highest role

Answer (score 0):

Your bot doesnt have permission to manipulate that members roles, consider:

```js
try{
  await member.roles.add(role);
}
catch(e){
  console.log(`Error adding role: ${e}`);
}
```

Comment: this won't work, `.add()` is a Promise and the rejection won't be caught